# LDAP PermGen memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, ldap, classloader, permgen

Whenever I use LDAP in a web application it causes a classloader leak, and the strange thing is profilers don’t find any GC roots.

I’ve created a simple web application that demonstrates the leak, it only includes this class:

```
@WebListener
public class LDAPLeakDemo implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) { 
        useLDAP();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

    private void useLDAP() {
        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        try {
            DirContext ctx = null;
            try {
                ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
                System.out.println("Created the initial context");
            } finally {
                if (ctx != null) {
                    ctx.close(); 
                    System.out.println("Closed the context");
                }
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/JohnA2/ldap-leak-demo). I’m using [a public LDAP test server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) for this example, so it should work for everyone if you want to try it.
I tried it with the latest JDK 7 and 8 and Tomcat 7 and 8 with the same result – when I click on Reload in Tomcat Web Application Manager and then on Find leaks, Tomcat reports that there’s a leak and profilers confirm it.

The leak is barely noticeable in this example, but it causes OutOfMemory in a big web application. I didn’t find any open JDK bugs about it.

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried to use Jetty 9.2 instead of Tomcat and I still see the leak, so it's not Tomcat's fault. Either it's a JDK bug or I'm doing something wrong.

**UPDATE 2**

Even though my example demonstrates the leak, it doesn’t demonstrate the out of memory error, because it has very small PermGen footprint. I’ve created [another branch](https://github.com/JohnA2/ldap-leak-demo/tree/outofmemory-demo) that should be able to reproduce OutOfMemoryError. I just added Spring, Hibernate and Logback dependencies to the project to increase PermGen consumption. These dependencies have nothing to do with the leak and I could have used any others instead. The only purpose of those is to make PermGen consumption big enough to be able to get OutOfMemoryError.

Steps to reproduce OutOfMemoryError:

1. Download or clone the [outofmemory-demo branch](https://github.com/JohnA2/ldap-leak-demo/tree/outofmemory-demo).
2. Make sure you have JDK 7 and any version of Tomcat and Maven (I used the latest versions - JDK 1.7.0_79 and Tomcat 8.0.26).
3. Decrease PermGen size to be able to see the error after the first reload. Create setenv.bat (Windows) or setenv.sh (Linux) in Tomcat’s bin directory and add `set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:PermSize=24m -XX:MaxPermSize=24m"` (Windows) or `export "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:PermSize=24m -XX:MaxPermSize=24m"` (Linux).
4. Go to Tomcat’s conf directory, open tomcat-users.xml and add `<role rolename="manager-gui"/><user username="admin" password="1" roles="manager-gui"/>` inside `<tomcat-users></ tomcat-users>` to be able to use Tomcat Web Application Manager.
5. Go to project’s directory and use `mvn package` to build a .war.
6. Go to Tomcat’s webapps directory, delete everything except the manager directory and copy the .war here.
7. Run Tomcat’s start script (bin\startup.bat or bin/startup.sh) and open http://localhost:8080/manager/, use username admin and password 1.
8. Click on Reload and you should see java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in Tomcat's console.
9. Stop Tomcat, open project’s source file `src\main\java\org\example\LDAPLeakDemo.java`, remove the `useLDAP();` call and save it.
10. Repeat steps 5-8, only this time there’s no OutOfMemoryError, because the LDAP code is never called.

Comment: Tomcat reports exactly what?

Comment: @EJP It shows its standard leak message - "The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory leak (use a profiler to confirm)".

Comment: That's because of a prior condition. You need to show us that. Retaining classes in memory isn't any kind of a memory leak over a long run. It is both normal and essential. Your growing memory problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @EJP What prior condition are you talking about? This example project contains only the class from my question. You can download the project from the link I gave and reproduce it. I know that the garbage collector doesn't always collect old classloaders, but if there's not enough space in PermGen, it must collect it to avoid out of memory error. Otherwise it just can't collect it due to a leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted this question. I finally found what really happened, so I thought I post it as the answer in case @MattiasJiderhamn or others are interested.

The reason profilers didn’t find any GC roots was because JVM was hiding the `java.lang.Throwable.backtrace` field as described in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8158237. Now that this limitation is gone I was able to get the GC root:

```
this     - value: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader #2
 <- <classLoader>     - class: org.example.LDAPLeakDemo, value: org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader #2
  <- [10]     - class: java.lang.Object[], value: org.example.LDAPLeakDemo class LDAPLeakDemo
   <- [2]     - class: java.lang.Object[], value: java.lang.Object[] #3394
    <- backtrace     - class: javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException, value: java.lang.Object[] #3386
     <- readOnlyEx     - class: com.sun.jndi.toolkit.dir.HierMemDirCtx, value: javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException #1
      <- EMPTY_SCHEMA (sticky class)     - class: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx, value: com.sun.jndi.toolkit.dir.HierMemDirCtx #1
```

The cause of this leak is the LDAP implementation in JDK. The `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx` class has a static filed

```
private static final HierMemDirCtx EMPTY_SCHEMA = new HierMemDirCtx();
```

`com.sun.jndi.toolkit.dir.HierMemDirCtx` contains the `readOnlyEx` field that is assigned to an instance of `javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException` during the LDAP initialization that happens after the `new InitialDirContext(env)` call in the code from my question. The issue is `java.lang.Throwable`, which is the superclass of all exceptions including `javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException`, has the `backtrace` field. This field contains references to all classes in the stacktrace at the time the constructor was called, including my own `org.example.LDAPLeakDemo` class, which in turn holds a reference to the web application classloader.

Here's a similar leak that was fixed in Java 9 https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146961

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Yes, the LDAP API provided by Sun/Oracle can trigger ClassLoader leaks. It is on [my list of known offenders](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2012/02/26/classloader-leaks-v-common-mistakes-and-known-offenders/), because if system property `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout` is > 0 `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapPoolManager` will spawn a new thread running in the web app that first invoked LDAP.

That being said, I added your example code as a test case in my [ClassLoader Leak Prevention library](https://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention), so that I'd get an automatic heap dump of the leak. According to my analysis, there is in fact no leak in your code, however it does seem to take more than one Garbage Collector cycle to get the ClassLoader in question GC:ed (probably due to transient references - haven't dug into it that much). This probably tricks Tomcat into believing there is a leak, even if there is none.

*However*, since you say you eventually get an `OutOfMemoryError`, either I'm wrong or there is something else in your app causing these leaks. If you add [my ClassLoader Leak Prevention library](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2012/03/04/classloader-leaks-vi-this-means-war-leak-prevention-library/) to your app, does it still leak/cause `OOME`s? Does the Preventor log any warnings?

If you set up your application server to create a heap dump whenever there is an `OOME`, you can look for the leak using Eclipse Memory Analyzer. I've explained the process in detail [here](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I’ve tried your library, but unfortunately it doesn’t help and doesn’t log any warnings. I’ve tried to use Eclipse MAT but the result is the same as with profilers – no strong and soft references to the classloader, but GC can never collect it. The leak happens only after the first redeployment, but the classloader stays in memory forever, no matter how many times I redeploy or use “Perform GC” in profilers. I’ve updated my question and added a webapp that actually produces OutOfMemoryError and the steps to reproduce it. I’d appreciate if you could try it.

Comment: Not sure when/if I'll find the time to test your example. Meanwhile: There must always be enough PermGen to hold at least 2 copies of the application, since the first copy usually won't be garbage collected before the second one is loaded. So if you get OOME on the first redeploy, your setting is too low to be a meaningful test. If you can redeploy once, force GC (System.gc() until a WeakReference is nulled) and then get it to crash on the next redeploy, then there is likely a real issue.

Comment: It leaks only once, so if I set PermGen size big enough, I won't get OOME. But it's still a leak, because I can set PermGen size slightly more than what is required to hold 2 copies, I can redeploy many times and see in a profiler how GC struggles to clean memory, but can never collect that first classloader. Forcing GC also doesn't help. If I just remove the `useLDAP()` call, I don't see this behavior anymore. Sure, I can live with this leak, but it would be good to know what causes it if there're no strong and soft references, and if there's a way to prevent it.

Comment: I would try another garbage collector, and see if the behaviour remains the same. Try for example `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`.

Also, would you like to share a heap dump for me to look at...?

Comment: `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` didn't help. I've uploaded the dump [here](http://wikisend.com/download/416316/java_pid3428.7z). To get this dump I followed steps 1-8 from my question, but also added `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` on step 3.

Comment: One thing you may want to try is to explicitly clear `com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.CACHE`.
(Unfortunately I haven't found the time to run the example it myself)

Comment: Clearing `com.sun.beans.TypeResolver.CACHE` didn't help. Another thing I tried before was clearing `com.sun.naming.internal.ResourceManager.propertiesCache`, but also without any success.